# Disallow index if typed by user

Tags: .htaccess

If a link is `http://example.com` it will redirect to `http://example.com/index.html` by default.
(or `.php` or anything like that).

But if the user types `http://example.com/index.html` in the url, I would like to show a 404 error.

I know I could do

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index.html 404.html [R=304,L]

But I would like something more general, that could work for every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule index\.(php|html?)$ 404.html [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Exactlty what I want! But I have one more question. Why is there `?` after `html` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (index.(html|php)|/foo/bar)
RewriteRule ^ 404.html [R=404,L]
```

Comment: Will it work for `http://example.com/foo/bar` ? And how can it work for every index (html and php and others)?